# Update/Merge my application.properties in Spring

Tags: spring-boot

In Spring boot i have an application.properties file

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
...
```

And i want to let the user from an interface change the property value like

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=225
```

Comment: use spring profile active

Comment: can you please provide an example thank you